# Parameter missing when connecting RecycleRview adapter to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to associate my `RecyclerView` adapter with a fragment but it is expecting another parameter at the adapter creation stage. I understand that something to do with `fm` needs to be included in the parameter but I'm not sure what I need to go there.

> No value passed for parameter 'fm'

**RecyclerView adapter class**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.companyname.appname.*
import com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dialog.view.*

class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Item>, private val fm: FragmentManager) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myBtn.text = (myList[position].textBtnTitle)
     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val myBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_a)!!

        init {
            myBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(myBtn.context)
                builder.setTitle(myList[position].txtDialogTitle)
                builder.setMessage(myList[position].txtDialogMessage)
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

                val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                dialog.show()

                tabLayout = customView.findViewById(R.id.mTabLayout)
                viewPager = customView.findViewById(R.id.mViewPager)

                val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(fm)
                adapter.addFragment("Tab A", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description A"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab B", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description B"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab C", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description C"))

                customView.mViewPager.adapter = adapter
                customView.mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(customView.mViewPager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TabbedDialogAdapter**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

class TabbedDialogAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    private var mFragmentCollection: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private var mTitleCollection: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    fun addFragment(title: String, fragment: Fragment) {
        mTitleCollection.add(title)
        mFragmentCollection.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mTitleCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentCollection.size
    }
}
```

**fragment class**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.companyname.appname.R
import com.companyname.appname.MyRVAdapter
import java.util.*

class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val myList = ArrayList<Item>()

        val mAdapter = MyRVAdapter(myList)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an IDE fault. Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding the project?

Comment: @RobPridham Yes but the error still remains. Did you check my code?

Comment: I looked over it, I haven't attempted to build it. The error would make sense if you failed to pass a fragment manager to `TabbedDialogAdapter`, but it doesn't make sense in the context you describe.

Comment: Can you expand out and include your imports in the code sample?

Comment: @RobPridham Sure. Just imnclude them for all classes.

Comment: Here: `val mAdapter = RVAdapterFacilities(facilitiesList)` aren't here missing additional parameter `getFragmentManager()`?

Comment: Yupi is right. I was being dim, and confused the fm parameter to `TabbedDialogAdapter` with the class `RVAdapterFacilities` that you haven't provided. Presumably this has an `fm` parameter that you haven't passed in.

Comment: @Yupi That code was for another project. I've changed it to the right code i.e. MyRVAdapter

Comment: @MacaronLover so that means you are missing a parameter which you have in constructor of your `adapter` here: `class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Item>, private val fm: FragmentManager)` so when you called `adapter` you provided only a list but missed `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a simple solution. You just forgot to provide one parameter. In your `adapter` constructor you have `ArrayList` and `FragmentManager`:

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Item>, private val fm: FragmentManager)
```

but when you called your `adapter` here: `val mAdapter = MyRVAdapter(myList)` you provided only `ArrayList` so one parameter is missing, and that is probably `getFragmentManager()` if adapter is created in `Fragment` in `Activity` it would be `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: `Type mismatch. Required: FragmentManager, Found: FragmentManager?`

Comment: Probably have selected (imported) wrong `FragmentManager`. Check imports on the top do you need: `android.app.FragmentManager` or `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`?

Comment: I got `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`. Just to clarify do I need to use `fragmentManager` or `childFragmentManager`?

Comment: Ah yes you are using `androidx` than check did you imported `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` and not using some another like I mentioned above

Comment: I imported `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` for all necessary classes. Should I be using `childFragmentManager` maybe?

Comment: In your `adapter` you named `FragmentManager` as `fm` but when creating `TabbedDialogAdapter` you are providing `childFragmentManager`? Code:
 `val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)` -> Shouldn't here be `fm` instead of `childFragmentManager`
Maybe mismatch is because of this, not sure.

Comment: I changed that to `fm` but the error is still there. This is a werid one as I have checked everything. For some reason, the error goes away when I use `val mAdapter = MyRVAdapter(myList, childFragmentManager)`

Comment: Does compiler leads you to the line where you have an error? Can you check that in Build, Debug or LogCat?

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f090100 (id/mViewPager) for fragment TabbedDialogFragment.

Comment: I think it's best to ask this in a new question

Comment: I've just asked a new question containing this [new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964427/dialogfragment-searching-for-incorrect-component)

Comment: @MacaronLover which one?

Comment: The question I asked on March 3rd (see link above called **new error**)

Comment: @MacaronLover says: Page not found

Comment: Here's the link to the [new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988756/viewpager-in-dialogfragment-missing-despite-already-existing)